# Named query not known: findById

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

I'm trying to build this simple project but I keep getting the same error. Can anybody help figure this out?

HibernateTest.java

```
public class HibernateTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();

        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findById");

        List<?> list = query.list();
        if (!list.isEmpty())
        { UserDetails userD = (UserDetails) list.get(0);
          System.out.println(userD); }
     }
}
```

UserDetails.java

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name="UserDetails")
@NamedQuery(
        name = "findById",
        query = "SELECT x FROM UserDetails x WHERE x.id = '3'")
public class UserDetails
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="UserID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="UserName")
    private String name;

    public void setId(int id)
    { this.id = id; }
    public int getId()
    { return id; }

    public void setName(String name) 
    { this.name = name; }
    public String getName()
    { return name; }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong because I have the same query running in a different project and it works fine.

Comment: Have you verified that the `UserDetails` class is known by your Hibernate configuration?

Comment: I have this in my hibernate.cfg.xml

<!-- Mapping files -->
      <mapping class = "com.UserDetails" />
      <mapping resource = "userdetails.hbm.xml" />

Comment: So... you are using XML mapping instead of annotation driven mapping?! Is the named query present in your `userdetails.hbm.xml` then?

Comment: That I don't. How do I put that in?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and i have resolved the issue by adding the following in `applicationContext.xml`.

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">  
              <list>
               <value>com.Employee</value>
               </list>  
               </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XML configuration, you can define a named query with the `<query>` tag. For example:

```
<query name = "findById">
    <![CDATA[SELECT x FROM UserDetails x WHERE x.id = '3']]>
</query>
```

The `<query>` tag is on the same level as the `<class>` tag, as a child of the `<hibernate-mapping>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

While this will not answer your immediate problem, if you are using Hibernate, and JPA annotations, why not using EntityManager instead of Hibernate session and stuff ?

With a Persistence Unit (as well as `persistence.xml` in your `META-INF` folder), you would do that:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findById");
```

Or better:

```
TypedQuery<UserDetails> query = em.createNamedQuery("findById", UserDetails.class);
```

The method are roughly the same (after all, JPA was made of Hibernate).